# Parse the email id from the email header using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, email-headers

I am sending an HTML email. In the content of that email, I have a submit button.

How do I make sure that the submit button was clicked by the same person to which the email was sent to and not some other person?

In order to achieve that, I will need to parse the email header and extract the email id from it using Javascript.

In short, how can we parse the email header in our Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

When you send an HTML email, you are just displaying an **HTML formatted document** to the user through their email client.

The Javascript code cannot parse the email header, in this case, since, the Javascript interpreter lies in the HTML document and doesn't know anything about the email. Anyways, if you want to retrieve the email id from the email header of an email which you have sent yourself, what don't you store it at the time of sending? But, this actually doesn't serve the purpose properly.

You cannot make sure that the submit button was clicked by the same person, since, he can always share the HTML document with somebody.

This type of authentication is not possible. Maybe, if you tell us the problem which you want to solve by this authentication, we can come up with some other form of authentication.

Comment: Thanks...  Actually we want to do some tracking based on submit button and we want to do tracking only to the user that we have sent mail to. Since this is important tracking , we don't want un-verified user to able to that.

Comment: Nope, you cannot do that. Email is one of the ways to ensure authentication. Maybe, you can restrict only a single use of the submit button, so the user won't share the email with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

- you cannot run JavaScript from your mail but you still can submit forms.
- for tracking users you can add to the form action URL the query string with some random number and save this number in a BackEnd before composing the email.
- if you have multiple recipients, you have to send the same mail multiple times to 1 recipient at a time with different tracking number in the form.